# How can I remove this MacBook Pro icon from the desktop?

Tags: icon, apple-silicon, ventura

I can remove the Macintosh HD icon from the desktop via the settings of the finder, but how to remove the other 'MacBook Pro' icon?

[image: screenshot]

Edit: it shows up after I changed the name of the Mac, however, changing it back doesn't help. And here is the icon's 'get info':

[image]

And these are the finder's preferences/settings, ticking off the boxes under the General tab or the Sidebar tab doesn't help either.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you tell what it is with Get Info? First thought would be a connected server - but that was always a drive image [haven't seen it on newer macOS]

Comment: Can you show us what your Finder Preferences look like?

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for your comments. I have added the information you requested.

Comment: @ErniePC12 thanks for your comments. I have added the information you requested.

Comment: What happens if you "eject" that Icon: select it and do a COMMAND-E. That would normally remove a mounted volume and tell you if it is indeed a volume or not.

Comment: @SteveChambers, no, nothing happened when pressing COMMAND-E, in fact, that typical 'eject' option is also not existent when right-clicking on that icon.

Comment: Is there anything related to the icon if you `ls -la ~/Desktop` in Terminal? Maybe there's some weird link...

Comment: Try unchecking each of the "Show these items on the desktop".

Comment: Thank you guys for checking this question out. That icon went away by itself after a fully shutdown of the Mac, and it never came back again. I will let you know if it ever shows up again :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to make this disappear is to right-click your desktop, click "Use stacks", then click "Use stacks" again.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks

Comment: This fixes it and it should be the accepted answer @user2165

Answer (score -2):

Use the keyboard shortcut
Control+Option+Command+O (Zero) and after Control+Option+Command+1

or go to Finder menu bar on, View >> Sort by >> None and after View >> Sort by >> Name or any order you want;

;-)

Comment: OP is not asking how to sort the icons, but how to remove a particular one.